# How do I limit an input to one letter?

Tags: python

Lets say I do this:
`letter = input('Please enter a letter: ')`

And I want to immediately stop the input after only one letter that the player typed.
How do I do it? Thanks!!

Comment: Use the `termios` module to change to raw mode, then use `sys.stdin.read` rather than `input`.